# How to run custom tasks in production by manually calling them?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, production-environment

I compile and deploy my Phoenix projects manually, with no third-party library such distillery, and with a help of the commands “mix compile” and “mix release”, basically.

I need a way to run custom commands or tasks on a server in the production mode. It’d be similar to running migrations. But I’ve bewildered as for how it’s done. A project itself may or may not be up and running when a command or task is being executed. And I need to be able to pass some arguments to a said command-task.

How to do it?

(1) I’m aware of

defmodule Mix.Tasks.MyTask1 do .... but how would I do it in production, on a server? Is this even a proper and recommended way to run them on a server in production?

(2) I’m aware of bin/my_app eval 'MyProject.MyTask1' but why does it exist if there’s the other abovementioned approach? Again, is this one a proper and recommended way to run them on a server in production?

(3) Are there other approaches?

I’m bewildered. Which one to use, in what circumstances? How to use them properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this that I'm aware of, each has their pros/cons.  Defining custom mix tasks, for example, is simple, but in your case, `Mix` is not available on a built+compiled release.

The solution I've usually landed on is to support a finite number of tasks (e.g. migrations): these are things that *must* be run occasionally/manually on a live production instance.  This is a bit more structured than a regular mix task, but it's written a way that works without mix. See the [Phoenix docs for an example](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/releases.html#ecto-migrations-and-custom-commands), but it boils down to calling the necessary functions from a regular module instead of via a mix task.  This assumes that you are able to connect to a running instance of your app via `iex` (e.g. by SSH'ing into the box and running `./bin/myapp remote` or similar).

This question may not generate high quality answers because any solutions are somewhat subjective.